# month name in Alias in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to have the month name in an Alias?

This code doesn't work but I'd want something like it. Thanks

provnam as datename(month,LSTCHG)

```
select county
,sum(case when svcdat between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-31' then units end) as jan_units
,sum(case when svcdat between '2022-02-01' and '2022-02-28' then units end) as feb_units
    from test
group by county
```

Comment: That would require dynamic sql. But why would you need to provide a dynamic alias to a column name like this?

Comment: I will have case statements in the select statement for each month of year is why.

Comment: Not sure why that means you have to have the name of the month. You can use your calculation as part of a case expression.

Comment: This sounds like a typical XY problem. Include your full SQL statement in your question.

Comment: I've updated to show what it currently looks like. I would like to schedule to have it run monthly but right now i have to manually enter the alias.

Comment: There are only 12 months. Surely you could have just written the 12 aliases and been done with this hours ago.

Comment: That is not how scheduled reporting works

Comment: No idea what that means. You see you have some details about what your requirements are but you are not sharing them. This still sounds like an https://xyproblem.info/ problem

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps find a way to work with the results if you return grouped results at a monthly level:

```
select 
    county, 
    datename(month, svcdate) as [Period], 
    sum(units) as SumOfUnits
from test
where
    svcdate >= '2022-01-01' and svcdate <= '2023-01-01'
group by 
    county, datename(month, svcdate)
```

by extension the grouping can include years of course too, and cover more than one annual period as well. This may make it all generally more flexible.